# Find CouchDB docs missing an arbitrary field

Tags: database, view, nosql, couchdb

I need a CouchDB view where I can get back all the documents that don't have an arbitrary field. This is easy to do if you know in advance what fields a document *might* not have. [For example](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/View_Snippets#Retrieving_documents_without_a_certain_field), this lets you send `view/my_view/?key="foo"` to easily retrieve docs without the "foo" field:

```
function (doc) {
  var fields = [ "foo", "bar", "etc" ];

  for (var idx in fields) {
    if (!doc.hasOwnProperty(fields[idx])) {
      emit(fields[idx], 1);
    }
  }
}
```

However, you're limited to asking about the three fields set in the view; something like `view/my_view/?key="baz"` won't get you anything, even if you have many docs missing that field. I need a view where it will--where I don't need to specify possible missing fields in advance. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

This technique is called *the Thai massage*. Use it to efficiently find documents *not* in a view if (and only if) the view is keyed on the document id.

```
function(doc) {
    // _view/fields map, showing all fields of all docs
    // In principle you could emit e.g. "foo.bar.baz"
    // for nested objects. Obviously I do not.
    for (var field in doc)
        emit(field, doc._id);
}

function(keys, vals, is_rerun) {
    // _view/fields reduce; could also be the string "_count"
    return re ? sum(vals) : vals.length;
}
```

To find documents not having that field,

1. `GET /db/_all_docs` and remember all the ids
2. `GET /db/_design/ex/_view/fields?reduce=false&key="some_field"`
3. Compare the ids from `_all_docs` vs the ids from the query.

The ids in `_all_docs` but not in the view are those missing that field.

It sounds bad to keep the ids in memory, but you don't have to! You can use a merge sort strategy, iterating through both queries simultaneously. You start with the first id of the *has* list (from the view) and the first id of the *full* list (from _all_docs).

1. If *full* < *has*, it is missing the field, redo with the next *full* element
2. If *full* = *has*, it has the field, redo with the next *full* element
3. If *full* > *has*, redo with the next *has* element

Depending on your language, that might be difficult. But it is pretty easy in Javascript, for example, or other event-driven programming frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the possible fields in advance, the answer is easy. You must create a new view to find the missing fields. The view will scan every document, one-by-one.

To avoid disturbing your existing views and design documents, you can use a brand new design document. That way, searching for the missing fields will not impact existing views you may be already using.