# Query for set complement in CouchDB

Tags: nosql, couchdb

I'm not sure that there is a good way to do with with the facilities CouchDB provides, but I'd like to somehow extract the relative complement of the sets of two different document types over a particular key.

For example, let's say that I have documents representing `user`s and `post`s, both of which have a (unique) `username` field.  There's a validation in place ensuring that a `user` document exists for the `username` in every `post`, but there may be any number `post` documents with a given `username`, include none.  It's trivial to create a view which counts the number of `post`s per `username`.  The view can even include zero-counts by emitting zero post-counts for the `user` documents in the view map function.  What I *want* to do though is retrieve just the list of users who have zero associated posts.

It's possible to build the view I described above and filter client-side for zero-value results, but in my actual situation the number of results could be very, very large, and the interesting results a relatively small proportion of the total.   Is there a way to do this sever-side and retrieve back just the interesting results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would write a map function to iterate through the documents and emit the users (or just usersnames) with 0 posts.

Then I would write a list function to iterate through the map function results and format them however you want (JSON, csv, etc).

(I would NOT use a reduce function to format the results, even if a reduce function appears to work OK in development.  That is just my own experience from lessons learned the hard way.)

Comment: I thought about a list function, but that (a) still has to linearly iterate through the entire view each time the underlying data changes, just does it server-side instead of client side; and (b) has to build the entire result-set in memory.  It would work, but I'm hoping there's a better solution.

Comment: The reason list functions have the quirky `while(row = getRow()) { ... }` stuff is to enable iterative processing *without* building the entire results. Simply `send()` if the row has 0 posts, and don't otherwise. There is still an O(n) *time* issue, but no *space* issues.

Comment: @jhs Oh, you're right.  I was unfairly projecting my frustration at how view `reduce` functions use the function return value onto innocent `lists` functions.  Good call!

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would filter on the client-side until I had performance issues. Next I would probably use Teddy's `_filter` technique—all pretty standard CouchDB stuff.

However, I stumbled across (IMO) an elegant way to find set complements. I described it when exploring [how to find documents *missing* a field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6183352/find-couchdb-docs-missing-an-arbitrary-field/6210422#6210422).

### The basic idea

Finding *non-members* of your view obviously can't be done with a simple query (and a straightforward index scan.) *However*, it can be done in constant memory, and linear time, by simultaneously iterating through *two query results* at the same time.

One query is for all possible document ids. The other query is for *matching* documents (those you *don't* want). Importantly, **CouchDB sorts query results**, therefore you can calculate the complement efficiently.

See my details in the previous question. The basic idea is you iterate through both (sorted) lists simultaneously and when you say "hey, this document id is listed in the full set but it's missing in the sub-set, that is a hit.

(You don't have to query _all_docs, you just need two queries to CouchDB: one returning all possible values, and the other returning values *not* to be counted.)