# couchdb -  retrieve documents for which an id is not included in an array property

Tags: couchdb, mapreduce

I have the following document structure in a couchdb database:

```
{
  'type': 'Message',
  'subject': 'Cheap V1@gr@',
  'body': 'not spam',
  'metadata': {
    'participation': {
      'read': [1,2,3]
    }
  }
}
```

The `read` array is a list of user ids who have read a message.  I can easily create a view to allow me to filter the list of messages by the messages a user has read, like so:

#### Map function

```
function(doc) {
  doc['metadata']['participation']['read'].forEach(function(user_id) {
    emit(user_id, doc._id);
  });
}
```

and then to execute the query for `user_id = 1`:

```
curl -X GET \
  http://localhost:5984/couchrest/_design/Message/_view/included_in_read?key=1
```

My question is: how would I go about writing a view/query to return documents for which the user's id is **NOT** included in the `read` array, i.e. "unread" messages.

Comment: Tiny tip: you don't need to emit the `doc._id`, because each row has an `id` field. Using `emit(user_id, 1)` saves disk space and bandwidth, speeding things up.

Comment: Thank you!  I did notice that the id existed in the resultset twice, now I understand why.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a technique called [the Thai massage](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/couchdb-user/201112.mbox/%3CCAN-3CB+++X3q=yt1YfJYRJW8f-zSFyJvbyGKQ1zx8h-QrE=9Mw@mail.gmail.com%3E).

The link above is my description of it in an email, and I described it in an answer to a similar question on Stack Overflow: [Find CouchDB docs missing an arbitrary field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6183352/find-couchdb-docs-missing-an-arbitrary-field/6210422#6210422)

I think the variation you would need to do is emit a 2-array for the key, `[user_id, doc_id]`. When you query for "hits" for user `1234`, use `?startkey=[1234,null]&endkey=[1234,{}]` to show only the hits for that user.

Comment: This is an interesting concept, I'm going give it a run and report back.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following Map function,

```
 function(doc) {
   if(!doc.metadata.participation.read)
     emit(doc.user_id, doc);
  }
```

and then to execute the query for user_id = 1:

```
curl -X GET \
http://localhost:5984/couchrest/_design/Message/_view/included_in_read?key=1
```

Comment: Wouldn't your solution emit all documents for which the read property is false?

Comment: Try once and let me know the result.